# SQL Server: join two tables using loop

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables. I am new to T-SQL.

First select returns this result:

```
ID  Quantity
-------------
1      30
2      25
```

Second select returns this result:

```
ID    Document   QuantityS    Date
----------------------------------------
 1    DocA          12        22-03-2017
 1    DocB          10        18-03-2017
 1    DocC          10        15-03-2017
 1    DocD           8         6-03-2017
 2    DocA          20        21-04-2017
 2    DocB          12        18-04-2017
 2    DocC          10        13-04-2017
```

I need to join this two table on ID and get rows from second table while sum of `quantityS` is bigger or equal to the `Quantity` from the first table, ordered by `Date desc`.

I need to get table like this:

```
ID    Document    QuantityS     Date
------------------------------------------
 1    DocA           12         22-03-2017
 1    DocB           10         18-03-2017
 1    DocC           10         15-03-2017
 2    DocA           20         21-04-2017
 2    DocB           12         18-04-2017
```

I don't need the last row from second table because the sum of quantity from three row is 32 which is bigger than 30.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were the results?

Comment: You are not joining two tables. If you join two tables by ID then you will have one row selected as you would see the common ID is 1.

Comment: I don't nothingabout this, i just join this two table on id but i don't now how to do this, whic loop to use and how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [windowed aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql):

```
SELECT ItemRecord.id, ItemRecord.document, ItemRecord.quantity, ItemRecord.uploadedOn
FROM ItemLimit
JOIN (SELECT ItemRecord.id, ItemRecord.document, ItemRecord.quantity, ItemRecord.uploadedOn, 
             COALESCE(SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY id 
                                         ORDER BY uploadedOn DESC 
                                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS runningTotal
      FROM ItemRecord) ItemRecord
   ON ItemRecord.id = ItemLimit.id
      AND ItemRecord.runningTotal <= ItemLimit.quantity
ORDER BY ItemRecord.id, ItemRecord.uploadedOn DESC
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/487f2/3/0)</kbd>

---

So how does this work?  The most important part is the aggregate function `SUM`.  You can't just use a regular one, though since you don't have (or even want) a `GROUP BY`, that means you need the `OVER` clause instead.  The first step:

```
SELECT id, document, quantity, uploadedOn, 
       SUM(quantity) OVER() AS runningTotal
  FROM ItemRecord
```

Results in:

```
| id | document | quantity | uploadedOn | runningTotal |
|----|----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | DocA     | 12       | 2017-03-22 | 82           |
| 1  | DocB     | 10       | 2017-03-18 | 82           |
| 1  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-03-15 | 82           |
| 1  | DocD     | 8        | 2017-03-06 | 82           |
| 2  | DocA     | 20       | 2017-04-21 | 82           |
| 2  | DocB     | 12       | 2017-04-18 | 82           |
| 2  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-04-13 | 82           |
```

...obviously the sum there is for the entire amount!  This reason is obvious: we haven't said what the "order" of the rows is!  So lets include the window in our next step:

```
SELECT id, document, quantity, uploadedOn, 
       SUM(quantity) OVER(ORDER BY uploadedOn DESC) AS runningTotal
FROM ItemRecord
```

Results in:

```
| id | document | quantity | uploadedOn | runningTotal |
|----|----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | DocA     | 12       | 2017-03-22 | 54           |
| 1  | DocB     | 10       | 2017-03-18 | 64           |
| 1  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-03-15 | 74           |
| 1  | DocD     | 8        | 2017-03-06 | 82           |
| 2  | DocA     | 20       | 2017-04-21 | 20           |
| 2  | DocB     | 12       | 2017-04-18 | 32           |
| 2  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-04-13 | 42           |
```

...except, for some reason, it didn't restart for `id = 1`!  We have to tell it to *partition*, or separate, the results:

```
SELECT id, document, quantity, uploadedOn, 
       SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY id 
                          ORDER BY uploadedOn DESC) AS runningTotal
FROM ItemRecord
```

Results in:

```
| id | document | quantity | uploadedOn | runningTotal |
|----|----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | DocA     | 12       | 2017-03-22 | 12           |
| 1  | DocB     | 10       | 2017-03-18 | 22           |
| 1  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-03-15 | 32           |
| 1  | DocD     | 8        | 2017-03-06 | 40           |
| 2  | DocA     | 20       | 2017-04-21 | 20           |
| 2  | DocB     | 12       | 2017-04-18 | 32           |
| 2  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-04-13 | 42           |
```

...well that's better, but we have a problem - we want row 3, but it's too high!  The catch is that we don't want the sum to include this row, but only the *preceding* rows.  Fortunately, we can specify the bounds of the window:

```
SELECT id, document, quantity, uploadedOn, 
       SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY id
                          ORDER BY uploadedOn DESC 
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS runningTotal
FROM ItemRecord
```

```
| id | document | quantity | uploadedOn | runningTotal |
|----|----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | DocA     | 12       | 2017-03-22 | (null)       |
| 1  | DocB     | 10       | 2017-03-18 | 12           |
| 1  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-03-15 | 22           |
| 1  | DocD     | 8        | 2017-03-06 | 32           |
| 2  | DocA     | 20       | 2017-04-21 | (null)       |
| 2  | DocB     | 12       | 2017-04-18 | 20           |
| 2  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-04-13 | 32           |
```

...okay, now the third row is in bounds, and the fourth row is (still) out of bounds, but we've got a problem with the *first* row: it's null!  This isn't too surprising: for the first row, there's no previous rows, so there isn't an amount.  It's annoying though: null doesn't compare with anything (even itself), so we can't use that in a simple comparison.  Fortunately, there's a way to change nulls into another value:

```
SELECT ItemRecord.id, ItemRecord.document, ItemRecord.quantity, ItemRecord.uploadedOn, 
       COALESCE(SUM(quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY id
                                   ORDER BY uploadedOn DESC 
                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                                AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS runningTotal
FROM ItemRecord
```

Which yields:

```
| id | document | quantity | uploadedOn | runningTotal |
|----|----------|----------|------------|--------------|
| 1  | DocA     | 12       | 2017-03-22 | 0            |
| 1  | DocB     | 10       | 2017-03-18 | 12           |
| 1  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-03-15 | 22           |
| 1  | DocD     | 8        | 2017-03-06 | 32           |
| 2  | DocA     | 20       | 2017-04-21 | 0            |
| 2  | DocB     | 12       | 2017-04-18 | 20           |
| 2  | DocC     | 10       | 2017-04-13 | 32           |
```

... and at this point, it's in the form we need, ready for a join to the other table with the limit.

---

As an aside, there's another way to remove the current row from the running total, and not need `COALESCE` either.  The current form of the query was chosen specifically because it meant the windows completely specified the desired rows.  This other version will be left as an exercise for the reader, or the performance-curious.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, but i modify my questions because i have more id to join. Can you help me to change code to work for this example, please ?